# fadeOut+delay not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a div overlaying the whole site to fade out when the page loads with a few seconds of delay. The div doesn not fade and I have no clue why...

```js
    $("#loading").delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
```

```css
    #loading {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 z-index:500;
 background:#000;
 position:absolute;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading"></div>
```

Comment: You need to describe what it's doing. Is it not delayed? Is it not fading out?

Comment: Seems to work just fine, even the snippet works just fine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `setTimeout()`

```
setTimeout(function () { 
    $("#loading").fadeOut(3000);
}, 3000);
```

From the [jQuery .delay() docs](http://api.jquery.com/delay/#entry-longdesc) :

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

Comment: Why? `.fadeOut()` is a queued jQuery effect. This is what `.delay()` is made for.

Comment: This is actually not one of those cases where `setTimeout` is more appropriate

Comment: @user3716760: You edited your question to say that the `div` doesn't fade at all. That shows that it has nothing to do with `.delay()`. Your actual issue may be that you're running your code before the DOM is loaded or that you're running your code before jQuery is loaded. This solution is the  *wrong* solution for any of those issues. If the DOM isn't ready, use `.ready()` with a callback. If jQuery isn't loaded, put your code below the jQuery `<script>`. But either way, `setTimeout` is a clunky solution that doesn't deal with the actual problem intelligently.

Comment: ...to be clear, the suggestion that `.delay()` isn't meant to be used to delay animations like `.fadeOut()` is entirely wrong. It's precisely what it's meant for.